# Not able to erase the added drawLine in swings

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, erase

I am trying to load a existing image and trying to edit it.

While trying to erase it. newly added is getting removed but the one which is added from image is not getting removed. can you please help me to erase it?

This is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class FreeHandDrawingToPdf {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public static int val = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DrawPad drawPad = new DrawPad();
        frame.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        JButton eraseButton = new JButton("Erase");
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box.add(saveButton);
        box.add(eraseButton);
        box.add(clearButton);
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                save(drawPad);
            }
        });
        eraseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (val == 0)
                    val = 1;
                else
                    val = 0;
            }
        });
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (val == 0)
                    val = 2;
            }
        });
        frame.add(box, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void save(Component frame) {
        BufferedImage bImg = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(),
        frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D cg = bImg.createGraphics();
        frame.paintAll(cg);
        try {
            if (ImageIO.write(bImg, "png", new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\karthik\\Desktop\\input\\output_image.png"))) {
                System.out.println("-- saved");
            }
            imageToPDF();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void imageToPDF() {
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        String pdfFilePath = "C:\\Users\\karthik\\Desktop\\input\\output_image.pdf";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    pdfFilePath);
            PdfWriter writer = null;
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, fileOutputStream);
            writer.open();
            pdfDocument.open();
            /**
             * Proceed if the file given is a picture file
             */

            pdfDocument.add(com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance("C:\\Users\\karthik\\Desktop\\input\\output_image.png"));

            /**
             * Proceed if the file given is (.txt,.html,.doc etc)
             */
            pdfDocument.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Document Exception!" + exception);
        }
    }
}
class DrawPad extends JComponent {
    Image image;
    Graphics2D graphics2D;
    int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;
    public DrawPad() {
        setDoubleBuffered(false);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
                if (FreeHandDrawingToPdf.val == 2) {
                    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
                    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
                    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
                    FreeHandDrawingToPdf.val = 0;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                if (FreeHandDrawingToPdf.val == 0) {
                    System.out.println("insde if");
                    if (graphics2D != null)
                        graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
                } else if (FreeHandDrawingToPdf.val == 1) {
                    // graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
                    // graphics2D.fillRect(currentX, currentY, 40, 40);
                    // graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
                    Graphics g = graphics2D;
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                    // g.fillRect(currentX, currentY, 40, 40);
                    g.clearRect(currentX, currentY, 40, 40);
                }
                repaint();
                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }
        });
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("draw");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\Karthik\\Desktop\\input\\output_image.png"));
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
                int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
                if (rgb != -1) {
                    g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Completed");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        try {

            if (image == null) {
                image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
                graphics2D = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
                graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                //clear();
            }
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

            draw(g);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DrawPad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Note : Download this [JAR FILE](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/itextpdf/5.0.6/itextpdf-5.0.6.jar) and link to the project to be able to work with `PdfWriter` and `Document`

Comment: *"Note : Download this JAR FILE and link to the project to be able to work with `PdfWriter` and `Document`"* Um... no thanks. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You may call repaint(); end of the lines in actionlistener of erase button. Or you can draw lines which have same color with background color.